# Problema al cargar audio con Android Studio

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un metrónomo y el problema que tengo es el siguiente.
Estaba utilizando un archivo de sonido de 1 segundo para hacer el sonido del metrónomo. El problema viene cuando el ritmo del metrónomo supera los 60 beats por segundo, porque al ser el audio de 1 segundo no puede superar esa velocidad. 
He probado a usar un archivo de audio de unos 0,25 segundos y al cargarlo en el Media Player no lo detecta y da el error de null pointer. He escuchado el archivo con el reproductor de windows y funciona bien, también está bien importado. ¿Alguien sabe cual es el problema?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button start, stop, tap;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private EditText e;
private boolean on = false;
CountDownTimer cdt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonidometronomo);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop);
    tap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Tap);
    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
                if(x > 0) {
                    long tiempoEnMilisegundos = 60000/x;
                    Log.d("MILIS", String.valueOf(tiempoEnMilisegundos));
                    cdt = new CountDownTimer(tiempoEnMilisegundos * 10, tiempoEnMilisegundos) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            mp.start();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            this.start();
                        }
                    };
                    cdt.start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(cdt!=null) {
                cdt.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: window.pruebaventanas, PID: 27973
>                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
>                                                                              at window.pruebaventanas.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
>                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10618)
>                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es debido a que al dar click al botón, la instancia del `MediaPlayer` tiene valor null.

Debes inicializar correctamente `mp` (`MediaPlayer`)  de esta forma:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonidometronomo);
```